# Can't log to Windows Events with syslog

Tags: 8, log-messages

**Problem:**

Our production server has IIS 7.5 (windows server 2008).
Syslog is enabled in Drupal. And works perfectly fine logging to Unix server syslog file. However, on the IIS (which doesn't have Syslog) there are 0 messages landing in the EventLog where it should appear.

**What I tried so far:**

- php.ini -> `error_log = "syslog"` (that I found on multiple Drupal forum for windows config)
- giving to the IUSR_... user the right permissions to wrote to the
  Event logs (we gave even administrator permissions)

**Misc:**

It's important to tell that the general error logging is WORKING. This means if a fatal error happens, and I set `error_log = "my_path/error.log"`, it shows there. However, caught exceptions won't be shown since they are handled by Drupal. That's why I need desperately the syslog on IIS (Windows Events). I am also aware of the existence of DBLOG, but in our use case we can't go with that solution.

Comment: I have't used syslog module but manual ```openlog ('foo', LOG_CONS, LOG_AUTHPRIV); syslog(LOG_ERR, $message);closelog();``` works for me.

Comment: On IIS you mean?

Comment: IIS is just webserver. This is about the platform(ie. windows).